Azure Data factory - ignore duplicates in destination?
I am retrieving data from a Sql database and want to insert into an Azure table storage.
However, I want to make sure I am not duplicate inserting data into the table storage.
How can I achieve this using ADF?
The uniqueness for me will be based on at least 2 columns. Let's say...
CustomerNumber
SubscriptionNumber
My query from Sql gets the data I need but want to ensure that dups are not inserted in Table storage.
I appreciate the guidance.

I know it doesn't help but azure tables doesn't really lend itself to this kind of operation. Is there any specific feature that azure tables provides that you want to utilise? What volume of data are you talking about?

Volume shouldn't be much. Azure table used as intermediate with querying that helps instead of using sql all the time for various reasons. Table storage is specific for this application. It's a good balance for me

What does much mean? 10 rows (entities) or 100,000? For small volume it's might be fine to do "update just in case" but I'm not an Azure table storage expert.

Let's say 5K max

and are you doing incremental loads from SQL, i.e. onloy loading changed records? Or are you loading all 5K every time? It doesn't sound like there is sufficient detail to provide much info

@Ahmedilyas, Do you want to ignore the duplicates in the source itself and then insert? or Do you want to ignore the duplicates in the source by comparing the existing target rows and source rows and then insert?

To ignore cups in destination. Source won't have them but possibly can in destination from previous run

You have a Merge option in Copy activity sink settings with Azure Table Storage as the sink. Provide a Row key column that serves as a unique identifier.
Below is the sink settings configuration.

Here, I have given:
Insert type : Merge
Row key column : ID
Below is the data in the CSV file and table storage.
In table storage

In CSV file

Now, I have changed the data with the same ID as shown below.

After running the copy activity, the data in table storage is:

and
In table storage

This way, you can have duplicates in the ID column and update new values to corresponding columns.
Unfortunately, you can specify only one column in the row key column.
